# How to upload milions object to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Google cloud storage API (XML or Json ) only permit 1 upload per second .

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques

> You can update a particular object up to once per second. Updating a particular object faster than once per second may result in 503 Service Unavailable errors. Concurrent updates to distinct objects are not subject to the one update per second limit.

So how to upload new 20 milions diffrence object google storage ?

P/s : i have ~20M small file in HDD , so i want to upload all to google cloud storage .

Comment: the question is, are you updating 1 object 20 million times or creating 20 million *new* objects?

Comment: i have ~20M small file in HDD , so i want to upload all to google cloud storage .

Comment: use the command line tool probably then....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, that wording is somewhat misleading. You may upload a particular object of the same object name once per second. If you have a bucket `foo` and an object `bar`, you should only upload a new copy of `foo/bar` about once per second.

You can upload objects with distinct names as fast as your bandwidth permits.

Comment: Are you sure ? I using hadoop (mapper only) to put using google storage , and an ramdomly hit  error (Backend error - 500 server status )

Comment: Yes, quite sure. 500s are certainly possible but should be quite infrequent. Do you seem them often?